# Add, remove and tune filters on running ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, effects

## Preface

I have been fiddling around with `ffmpeg` and `ffplay` using command line adding and tuning filters and effects.

It quickly becomes rather tiresome to

1. start playback with some audio file
2. stop
3. modify command
4. back to 1.

When for example fine-tuning noise reduction or adding effects and equalizer.

I have played around with using `zmq` to tune filters by executing commands in a different terminal, but this also becomes somewhat cumbersome.

I want some interface where I can add, remove and tune filters ***during runtime / while listening to the changes taking effect***.

## FFMPEG

I use `filter` to mean *effect / filter* from here on out. For example `afftdn`, `rubberband`, ...

`ffmpeg` is somewhat intimidating. It's powerful but also complex, at least when starting to dig into it. :0

Looking at the library and examples I am looking at [API example for audio decoding and filtering](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/filtering_audio_8c-example.html), - which at least at first looks promising as a starting platter.

#### Output

I imagine it would be best to have multiple *sinks* or some container with multiple audio tracks:

1. Raw audio
2. Audio with effects applied

Optionally:

1. Raw audio
2. Audio with all filters
3. Audio with filter group 1
4. Audio with filter group 2
5. ... etc.

---

#### Processing

I imagine the routine would have to be something like:

1. Read packet from stream/file/url
2. Unpack the sample
3. Copy / duplicate sample for each filter group / or one for filters
4. Apply filter(s) to these “effect sample” (s)
5. Write *raw* audio, *filtered* audio 1, *filtered* audio 2, *filtered* audio N, ...  to out

Or for step 3 - 5 (as one would only be listening to *one track* at a time (But this is perhaps not the best if one decide to jump back / forth in the audio stream):

3. Apply currently active filter(s)
4. Write *raw* audio, *filtered* audio to out

Simultaneously one would read and check changes to filters by some interface. I.e. input:

```
afftdn=rf=-20:nr=20
```

then, if `afftdn` is not present in filters add it, else set new values.

Idea is to output "raw-audio". I.e. used in a sampling and tuning phase - then produce a line with filter-options one can use with the `ffmpeg`-tool to process the audio files once satisfied.

## Questions section

- Does something similar exist?

General:

- Does this seem like a way to do it and use the `ffmpeg` library?

  - Can one add, remove and change filter values during runtime or do one have to re-initialize the entire stream for each added / removed filter etc?
  - Is the *“Processing”* part sound?
- Would using a container that supports multiple audio tracks be the likely best solution? E.g. mp4.

  - Any container preferred over others?
  - Any drawbacks (i.e. jumping back / forth in the stream)

---

## Sub-note

Dream is to have a Arduino interfacing with this program where I use physical rotary switches, incremental rotary encoders, buttons and whistles. Tuning the various options for the filters using physical knobs. But at first I need some working sample where I use FIFO or what ever to test `ffmpeg` itself.

Comment: ffmpeg is not meant to be an interactive editor, certainly not a realtime one. Filters can't be inserted mid-way.

Comment: @Gyan one can modify filters using `zmq` in both `ffplay` and `ffmpeg` and I am talking about the API as linked in question. Thought that if one can modify one could also apply and remove ...

Comment: With regard to the FFMPEG API , are you using C? If you’re using C, do you have an example of applying a single, static filter rather than the dynamic one you are aiming for?

Comment: @fdcpp Yes, it's the C API. In short: no. But looking at the `ffplay` code it looks like it might be possible. One can *modify* the set filters during playback, - so thought *adding* a filter would also be possible.

Comment: Via the CLI interface, probably not, or at least not easily. In any case I’d make an attempt at using the C API if only to get a feel for ease of use.

Comment: @fdcpp: Yes. I meant using the C API. Sorry if that was not clear. (I said no to "do you have an example of applying a single, static filter". Not beside the sample linked in Q or looking at the ffplay code e.g. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffplay.c#L2067 – anyhow, I got stuck with some other work that takes all my time now so have to look at it later.

Comment: Hey @Turmund! Have you succeeded with applying filters dynamically?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/hdb/mpv-live-filters

Answer (score 0):

Use mpv with IPC. You then add, remove, toggle audio or video filters in realtime via shell.